# How to Call Web API from Another MVC Project with two Parameter one in header and second in body

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I want to call api action from from mvc project but i have an issue API action have two parameter one in header and second in body.

Comment: **ASP.NET MVC** = web app framework on the **full, classic .NET** Framework (up to v4.8) - **ASP.NET Core MVC** = web app framework on the new, cross-platform, **.NET Core** platform - so which one are you talking about here? Please be **precise** (in your text, in your tags chosen)! They are closely related - but not identical....

Comment: If you need some help you have to post the view and the controller action code and url you are trying  to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a HttpClient object and set the header parameter

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:64189/api/");
    
    //your header parameter name and value
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("hdrname", "hdrvalue"); 
    
    //HTTP GET
    var responseTask = client.GetAsync("youraction?param1=abc"); //Action Name
    responseTask.Wait();

    var result = responseTask.Result;
    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // Use your class model to receive the data from the API
        var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<YourModel>>();
        readTask.Wait();

        var r = readTask.Result;
    }
    else //web api sent error response 
    {
        //log response status here..
    }
}
```